# Wrapping the HTML Control on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm writing an app (C++ with VS20050 for Windows Mobile, which wraps the HTML
Control (that is, I'm creating a DISPLAYCLASS window).

I want to be able to create a HTML page, and by using JavaScript on
the page, cause a function in my app to be executed.  Almost like JNI
in Java.

What I have been doing is, on the page, executing the line

document.location.href="myapp:myfunc";

and my app looks for "myapp:" when my app receives NM_BEFORENAVIGATE
from the control.  This seems to work (emphasis on the word "seems.")
Something that breaks as a result of this is that the javascript code
on the page breaks at the point that I attempt to submit the form on
the page.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Regards,
Brian

Comment: You need to provide us with a bit more info. What do you mean with the JS code breaks when submitting the form? Does it generate a JS error? If so, can you tell us what it says?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call JS->Java ? If so, you can start with an ActiveXControl which can use JNI to call Java.

Comment: No, he states his app is written in C++, so JNI wouldn't work.

Comment: Then JS->ActiveXControl->C/C++ Method without the JNI part. I have done this. We need to make sure that ActiveXControl's DLL refers to the C/C++ method DLL.

I was even able to merge them into one DLL.